# How to use Clojure to run system administration and deployment tasks over SSH?

Tags: build, clojure, system-administration

Python has the Fabric library to perform such actions, does Clojure have options like that ?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: This question has a defined answer, (Pallet) and it is provided below. This question should be taken off hold so the answers can be improved.

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look to [stevedore](https://github.com/pallet/stevedore), it's used extensively in `pallet`.

From the [script reference](http://palletops.com/doc/reference/script/):

```
(use '[pallet.stevedore :only [script with-script-language]])
(use '[pallet.script :only [with-script-context]])
(require 'pallet.stevedore.bash) ;; for bash output

(with-script-language :pallet.stevedore.bash/bash
  (with-script-context [:ubuntu]
    (script
      ("ls")))
```